# Moving photos from iphone to ubuntu

Tags: iphone, photo

From Ubuntu 10.04 onward, you can access your iPhone photos by simply connecting it and navigating to the `DCIM` folder.
However, I've noticed that when I move photos from my iPhone by cutting them from the `DCIM` folder and pasting them somewhere on my ubuntu setup, the photos' thumbnails remain in the camera roll however when clicking on a photo to view it, the screen turns white. Restarting the phone doesn't help as well.
How come?
**How can I move photos out of the phone without keeping its thumbmail in the camera roll?**

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, iphone 5S with iOS 7.1.1

Comment: Here's the [same question from an iPhone perspective](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136102/photo-thumbnails-remain-in-camera-roll-after-moving-photos-to-computer/136225)

Answer (score 1):

A hacky and maybe risky workaround which worked for me was suggested [here](http://support.digidna.net/entries/23455071-Modifying-the-Camera-Roll-Contents-Pictures-Thumbnails-):

- Go to `PhotoData` folder
- Delete `Photos.sqlite`
- Restart the iPhone

Comment: I'd definitely appreciate another answer which explains why this happens and that offers a non-hacky-risky solution

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too much risk to deleting Photos.sqlite if you're moving *all* of your pictures manually. That's a SQLite database file that is generated by the iPhone photo app that contains metadata and an autogenerated thumbnail for each photo as it's taken. If you delete it, your iPhone will just make a new one.

Be it known that if you're only moving some of your pics, I have no idea what deleting the DB file might do. It might rebuild with the photos you still have, it might just lose access to them through the app but leave them on internal storage, it might lose them forever.